# How to get a list link image from HTML with HTMLReader library on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, get

I am an Swift beginner and currently building an ios that extracts image from HTML Pages unsplash. I am using HTMLReader to get list image's link. But I get nill.
Could anyone help me of how to extract image urls from web pages using htmlreader? Below is what I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let sessionConnection = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let dataTask = sessionConnection.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "https://unsplash.com/")!,completionHandler:{(data,response,error)-> Void in
        let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let document = HTMLDocument(string: string)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.getGenresList(document)
        }
        })
dataTask.resume()
}

func getGenresList(document: HTMLDocument) {
    let mainGenres = document.nodesMatchingSelector("div > div > div > div > a > img")
    NSLog("sectionGenre = \(mainGenres)")
    for liNode in mainGenres {
        let sectionGenre = (liNode as HTMLElement).firstNodeMatchingSelector("img")
        var urlString = sectionGenre.attributes("src")
        NSLog("sectionGenre = \(urlString)")

    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like it requires https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader

Answer (score 0):

i fixed.

```
    func getGenresList(document: HTMLDocument) {
        let mainGenres = document.nodesMatchingSelector("div > div > div > div > div > a")
        NSLog("\n \n \n mainGenres = (mainGenres) \n \n")
        NSLog("\n \n \n \n \n")
        for liNode in mainGenres {
            let sectionGenre = (liNode as HTMLElement).firstNodeMatchingSelector("img")
            var urlString: AnyObject = sectionGenre.attributes["src"]!
            NSLog("sectionGenre = (urlString)")
```

`}`